# In MS Excel, how do I find the nth value in vlookup when your range has duplicate lookup values

Tags: excel, vlookup

Ok, let me see if i can phrase this properly.  I have a table with values I want to search that have duplicate items in the reference column but i want the lowest value in the adjacent column.  I've sorted according to the reference column then the column with the values in ascending order. For normal look-ups the vlookup function returns the first row and that suits me for normal searches. The caveat here is that my reference column values contain wildcards and when it it finds similar items it returns the values from the last instance;  here is my issue:

```
1. Item     Value 
2. abc*      3 
3. abd*      5
4. abe*      4
5. abe*      6
```

I want my vlookup to return the first instance of abe* of 4 but it always gets the second or last instance of 6.  Since I'm searching in items containing wildcards I use the parameter FALSE for the closest match. I don't understand why it wont return the first instance.  Am I missing something? Is there a better function to do what I need?

I apologize if this is the wrong venue for my question.  Please direct me to the correct one if I am in error.

Comment: please post your formula too. If I use VLOOKUP("abe*",A1:B4,2,false) I get 4.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mis-stated the parameter I was using.  I use the TRUE parameter.  If I use the FALSE parameter I get no return at all. here is my formula: =IF(U115="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A115,LEN(A115)-4),'SPAs 2'!A$366:F$610,3,TRUE),""))

Comment: What does your data look like? Also, the table has to be sorted on the lookup column in order for VLOOKUP to return anything with TRUE. Finally: you do know TRUE may return results NOT equal to the find string?

Comment: jk, I'm well aware of how VLOOKUP works.  If you had read my comment entirely you have seen where I said my data was sorted in ascending order.  I'm also well aware of what the TRUE parameter does.  It is precisely why I used it.  I wanted the closet match that it would find.  FALSE requires an exact match.  What my issure is, had you read through the comments, was why VLOOKUP returns the last item instead of the first item when using the TRUE parameter with regards to identical items found.  FALSE will return data from the first row of identical items. Thank you just the same.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your need at first, hence my questions. I guess all you can do is something like: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A115,LEN(A115)-4),'SPAs 2'!A$366:F$610,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A115,LEN(A115)-4),'SPAs 2'!A$366:F$610,3,TRUE)

Comment: Also,  If I remove the IFERROR segment, the formula works.